# Casting Date type to only display time

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime, datetime-format

In my database(an Oracle 11 database) I have a attribute which is of Date type but has a time in the value for some reason, idk why it is Date type and not DateTime. When I select this " Position_time" Of course it just displays the date but when i attempt a filter on the column more options are shown of the same date for multiple times so a time value is present in this column even though it is of date type.
[Link to picture of position_time context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKhNQ.png)

As seen in the image even though the attribute is of type Date it contains a time "component" This is not shown in the overview btw only when i try to filter the column idk of that matters.

Id like to extract this time from my date. I've seen plenty of posts explaining how to extract from a DateTime column but not from a Date. I cannot change the type of this column. Is there any way to achieve this?
for example

```
select
format(tr.position_time)
from positions
```

Comment: In your screenshot there is `position_date` and `position_time`. Why do you have separate columns for date and time to start with? Are you dealing with repetition (e.g. every day at eight) or what is the reason for this? Unfortunately Oracle has no data types for date and time, it only has a datetime type which it calls `DATE` to make things worse. Storing date and time separately in two date(time) columns forces you to use date/time functions whenever you want them combined.

Comment: @johnlogistic1 If you want to un-delete your recent [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59106772/resolving-subquery-not-allowed-here-subquery-in-group-by-error) I've got an answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this :

```
    select to_char(to_date(position_time,'dd-mm-yyyy HH24:MI:SS'),
'HH24:MI:SS') time from positions;
```

if you already passing the date type as parameter then just use `to_char` function for extract the time from it.

E.g:

```
Select to_char(position_time,'HH24:MI:SS') from positions;
```

Answer (score 0):

You would convert to a string:

```
select to_char(tr_position_time, 'HH24:MI:SS')
from positions;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, `date` datatype consist of date + time.

It is the `NLS` setting of your IDE which is displaying the data like this.

If you want to show date and time then use:

```
select
To_char(tr.position_time,'dd-mon-rrrr hh24:mi:ss')
from positions
```

Or if you want just time portion then use:

```
select
To_char(tr.position_time,'hh24:mi:ss')
from positions
```

If you want to see all the dates in your session with time then alter your session's `NLS` setting.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

select
tr.position_time -- formatting is not needed
from positions
```

In your IDE also, there must be setting to change the `NLS` setting.

Cheers!!